# Packing keyword arguments in Racket?

Tags: racket, keyword-argument, argument-unpacking

Is there a way to specify keyword arguments to a function as a dictionary, analogously to the `.` that allows us to supply a list for positional arguments? I'm looking for something analogous to python's [*args and **kwargs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/).

**In more detail**:

If we want to handle an arbitrary number of *positional* arguments in a function, we can define it like so:

```
(define (my-add . args)
  (apply + args))
```

and use it with a variable number of arguments as:

```
(define numbers '(1 2 3))
(apply my-add numbers) ;=> 6
(define numbers '(1 2 3 4 5))
(apply my-add numbers) ;=> 15
```

Even for functions that don't explicitly handle the "rest" of the positional arguments via the `.` syntax, we can use `apply` to unpack positional arguments from a list.

```
(apply expt '(2 3)) ;=> 8
```

I see that `apply` [does forward on keyword argument](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29)s in addition to positional arguments. However, this only works if the invoked function itself identifies the specific keyword arguments it is expecting. For instance, in a dispatch situation where the function doesn't itself use the keyword arguments but merely intends to forward them on to some appropriate handler, using apply in this way doesn't do what we need because the function would need to know about all the keyword arguments accepted by any function it is dispatching to, not to mention do the legwork of repacking them in some way before invoking the handlers.

As a tangible example illustrating the problem, consider a simple "echo args" function that echoes all of the arguments passed to it:

```
(define (echo-args . args)
  (printf "~a" args))
```

With only positional args:

```
> (echo-args 1 2 5)
(1 2 5)
```

With keyword args:

```
> (echo-args 1 2 5 #:key 'hi)
; application: procedure does not accept keyword arguments
;   procedure: echo-args
;   arguments...:
;    1
;    2
;    5
;    #:key 'hi
; Context:
;  /Applications/Racket v7.5/collects/racket/repl.rkt:11:26
```

Is there a built-in way to accomplish this kind of thing? If not, any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: try "hash-lambda" package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `make-keyword-procedure`. This generates a procedure that accepts all keyword arguments, and can be accessed from a dictionary.Taking the example from the docs:

```
> (define show
    (make-keyword-procedure (lambda (kws kw-args . rest)
                              (list kws kw-args rest))))
> (show #:blue 3 4)
'((#:blue) (3) (4))
```

Of course, a dictionary implemented as two lists can be a bit annoying. So Alex Knauth made a small package [hash-lambda](https://docs.racket-lang.org/hash-lambda-toc/index.html) which gives you a more direct hash-map like API.

Comment: This looks handy. For completeness, this is one half of what I'm looking for as it allows us to _define_ functions taking in keyword arguments as a hash. The other half is supplying such kwargs as a hash to a normal function which may not already be defined this way. For that, looks like we can use [apply/kw-hash](https://docs.racket-lang.org/kw-utils/kw-hash_scrbl.html?q=kw-utils#%28def._%28%28lib._kw-utils%2Fkw-hash..rkt%29._apply%2Fkw-hash%29%29). It would be nice if this duality could be eliminated somehow (e.g. the alluded-to behavior in python)... but maybe it's not that easy.

Comment: Ya, `apply/kw-hash` is the best I've seen. Although built into racket there is `keyword-apply`. which acts as the duel to `make-keyword-procedure`. Maybe I should update the answer to include it?

Comment: Sure, that would be great. Also another note ftr: `apply/kw-hash` / `keyword-apply` work with any function, whether it is a normal function or one that's defined via `make-keyword-procedure`.

Comment: Recently came across the [arguments](https://docs.racket-lang.org/arguments/index.html) package, as another alternative.